# SqlBulkCopy - Add rows along with additional values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying a code snippet that add excel data into sql database using SqlBulkCopy. The code snippet is as given below

```js
OleDbConnection connection=null;
        string FilePath="";
         try
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFolder/"+FileUpload1.FileName));
                    FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFolder/"+FileUpload1.FileName);
         
                }

                string path = FilePath;
                // Connection String to Excel Workbook
                string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);
                connection = new OleDbConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
                connection.Open();
                // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                // SQL Server Connection String
                string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=sample;Initial Catalog=ExcelImport;User ID=sample;Password=sample";

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
                SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
                bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "Customer_Table";
                bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
                Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFolder/")), File.Delete);
            }
```

This add the data from excel file to sql server database table. But my requirement is that I need to add the values of excel sheet plus additionally my own values say autogenerated studentid.

So my question is how I will add new values (say studentid, batchcode etc) along with values that read from excel. And these values to be added to each row of excel data.

Example:-

excel contains following columns

**CustomerID,City,Country,PostalCode**

Now I need to add values to sql server by adding some new columns as

**StudentID,CustomerID,BatchCode,City,Country,Email,PostalCod**e

How can I do it

Please help

Comment: Where the data for the additional columns come from and how it is related/associated with the data record from Excel? For instance, in your example, for each Excel record what would be the values of **StudentID, BatchCode, Email** columns.

Comment: @IvanStoev these values can be from a different function or from a control. For instance I have a method which creates auto generated studentid and batchcode can be retrieved from a dropdown list

Comment: Is the answer below ok for you? Technically it is working, but not space efficient.

Comment: @IvanStoev : The code is working fine. But is there any other efficient way. Please suggest

Comment: By space inefficient I meant that data table uses memory (in fact the whole data is loaded in memory just to be send to the db for bulk insert).  And yes, there are other ways that can avoid this, but more complicated, so if memory is not a problem (i.e. your data is not so big), then you'd better use this approach.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for the info. For the time being I hope I will not get problem with memory. Anyhow I appreciate the efforts you have taken. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  do the following:

- load the excel data into a data table,
- Add the remaining columns to the data table,
- Set new column values
- SqlBulkCopy the data table into SQL Server.

Something like this:

```
DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

DataTable table = new DataTable("Customers");
table.Load(dr);
table.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("BatchCode", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    row["StudentId"] = GetStudentId(row);
    row["BatchCode"] = GetBatchCode(row);
    row["Email"] = GetEmail(row);
}


// SQL Server Connection String
string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=sample;Initial Catalog=ExcelImport;User ID=sample;Password=sample";

// Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "Customer_Table";
bulkInsert.WriteToServer(table);
```